# How to catch/handle number format exception in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, exception, error-handling, number-formatting

I would like to add 'try catch' statement on the module that I'm creating. I want to specify the exception to be caught in number format. This is the sample code,

```
    Try
       interest = me.txtInterest.text
       principal = me.txtPrincipal.text
       totalPayment = interest + principal
    Catch ex As Exception 'What is the proper exception for Number Format?
        MsgBox("Number Format Error")
    End Try
```

I want to specify the exception to number format. How could I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'number format', can you give an example of a valid and invalid value?

Answer (score 2):

use this sample code

```
   Try
            Dim no1 As Integer = Int16.Parse(Me.TextBox1.Text)
            Dim no2 As Integer = Int16.Parse(Me.TextBox2.Text)
            Dim toatlPayment As Integer = no1 + no2


        Catch ex As FormatException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching the exception, you could check if it's a valid number

```
If Int32.TryParse(me.txtInterest.text, interest) AndAlso Int32.TryParse(me.txtPrincipal.text, principal) Then
    totalPayment = interest + principal
Else
    MsgBox("Number Format Error")
End If
```